# Reading from file in Linux

Tags: linux, file-io, read-write

I have to read from file and assign values to variables. Then I have to save them in another file. I know how to do the second and third part but I don't know how to read from file.

The sample file looks like this. how do I eat up unwanted things like Points, newline and store values somewhat like a = 21, b = 8 and so on.

(Please note there is no empty line after A 21. Assume it as A 21\nB 8 and so on)

```
Points:

A 21 
B 8
C 2
D 13
E 24
```

Comment: Hey look-up `sed` it will have the functioanlity your looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the variables are empty. Something like this:

```
while read -r var val; do 
    [[ ! -z $var && ! -z $val ]] && echo "$var=$val"
done < file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
Points:

A 21
B 8
C 2
D 13
E 24
$ while read -r var val; do [[ ! -z $var && ! -z $val ]] && echo "$var=$val"; done < file
A=21
B=8
C=2
D=13
E=24
```

---

To answer your question in comments…

```
$ . <(while read -r var val; do [[ ! -z $var && ! -z $val ]] && echo "$var=$val"; done < file)
$ echo $A
21
$ echo $B
8
```

Comment: So you saved the imput file as file with no extension

Comment: @user1598734 Linux generally does not use the file extensions. Some application programs that run on them do need extension to be present with the file name but this is just the limitation of the application and not the OS

Comment: I actually did not mean to save a=21 and b=8. I wanted to have variables a,b,c and Assign values to them. Not save in file. Sorry if I should have told that properly.

Comment: @user1598734 No problem. I have updated the solution to answer that. Good luck!

Comment: I get following error
code.sh: line 1: unexpected argument `&&' to conditional unary operator
code.sh: line 1: syntax error near `&'
code.sh: line 1: `(while read -r var val; do [[ ! -z  && ! -z  ]] && echo =; done < file; )'

Comment: @user1598734 You need to show your script. It is difficult to understand the issue from this error message.

Comment: (while read -r var val; do [[ ! -z  && ! -z  ]] && echo =; done < file; )

Comment: Where are the variables in test and echo statements? Check my answer carefully.

Comment: `while read -r var val; do [[ ! -z $var && ! -z $val ]] && echo "$var=$val"; done < file)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm **underthinking** this, but wouldn't this do the job?

```
sed 's/ / = /' file > newfile
```

Comment: I am very new to Linux, so could you please explain.

Comment: Using sed, the **stream editor**.  A search & replace operation, looking for the first occurrence of a space, and replacing it with a space, followed by and equal-sign, followed by a space.  Read a good sed tutorial ;}   http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html